# LIKE or REGEX trouble

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I'm tyring to pull everything out of a column when the word `assistant` is present with something like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE '%assistant%'
```

but this is not working. I am not getting an error and it is filtering the data somehow but it appears to actually be filtering my requested values OUT (I have verified the values exist). Can anyone explain what is wrong with attempt or how I can do this in regex with `REGEXP_LIKE`?

For regex, the pattern would be `anythingASSISTANTanything`

Comment: The above code looks correct for selecting any value that contains the string "assistant". Can you provide a sample of the data that you are expecting this to return? Also, double check that you're actual code matches the sample above.

Comment: Just FYI: you need no `anything` in a regex since `REGEXP_LIKE` is able to find partial matches in strings.

Comment: The `LIKE` pattern specifies `assistant` in lower case, but where you describe the regex pattern you use upper case. Keep in mind that both `LIKE` and `regexp_like` in Presto are case-sensitive, so make sure your pattern matches the case in your data.

Comment: Make sure that the correct column you want to have assistant is in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
WHERE LOWER(field) LIKE '%assistant%'
```